# Oracle SQL - Need to update 2 rows in Single update query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can we able to update the 3 fields in first row and 1 field in second row through SINGLE update statement. all key fields are different between 2 rows except one key. If possible please let me know.

For Ex:

Employee has 2 rows of data in one table. I am going to update name , location , pincode in first row and going to update salary type in second row

Comment: Could you prepare example of your problem in http://sqlfiddle.com/?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. Pseudo-code:

```
update table
set 
col1 = case when rowid = 1 then value1 else col1, --Only update with new value for row 1
col2 = case when rowid = 1 then value2 else col2,
col3 = case when rowid = 2 then value3 else col3, --Only update with new value for row 2
...
where rowid in (col1,col2)
```

Comment: Its just confusing.. I will give the sample data.. Please give me the solution based on that.  Table Name - VV_DATA Emplid = 10000 and Set_id = 232323 SYS_ID = 45454 for first row and table Name - VV_DATA Emplid = 10000 and Set_id = 254544 SYS_ID = 89855.